# MockRestServiceServer doesn't get invoke in tests

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-test

I have created a few classes to test a RestTemplate client. The service can be called from Postman with no issues. However, when I call the service using the MockRestServiceServer, the assertion fails. the endpoint does not seem to be called.

Here is the test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RestClientTest([ Config.class, UserService.class])
class UserServiceSpec  extends Specification{
 Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceSpec)

@Autowired
UserService service

@Autowired
MockRestServiceServer server;

@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

def setup() {
    User user = createUser()
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user)
    this.server.expect(requestTo("/user/{type}"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andExpect(requestToUriTemplate("/user/{type}",Type.Business.name()))
            .andExpect(content().json(json, "UTF-8"))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(json, APPLICATION_JSON))
}
@Test
def "User creation should be successful"(){
    given:
    User user = createUser()
    when:
     User result = service.createUser(user, Type.Business)
    then:
    result!=null
}

static User createUser(){
    User user = new User()
    user.firstName = 'Cassie'
    user.class = Type.Business.name()
    user.lastName = 'Wayne'
    user.age = 39
    return user
 }
}
```

Here are the other classes

```
@Configuration
class Config{

 @Bean(name = "userRestTemplate")
 public RestTemplate userRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder, 
 @Value("${user.service.client.uri}") String uri){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = builder.rootUri(uri)
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000 * 60))
            .build();
    System.out.println("URI :: "+uri);
    return restTemplate;
   }
 }




 @Service
 public class UserService  {

 private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);
 @Autowired
 private RestTemplate userRestTemplate;

 public User createUser(User user, Type type){
    Map<String,String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
    uriVariables.put("type", type.name());
    HttpEntity<User> request = new HttpEntity<>(user);
    return userRestTemplate.postForObject("/user/{type}",request,User.class, uriVariables);
 }
```

}

```
application-test.properties

user.service.client.uri=http://localhost:8080
```

The error is as follows

java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected: HTTP POST user/business
0 request(s) executed.

Comment: I think the problem is `this.server.expect(requestTo("/user/{type}"))` looks like you did not define `{type}` value

Comment: the error shows that the type is bound, i.e. /user/business. Here is where I am setting it. Map<String,String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
    uriVariables.put("type", type.name());